# Function form to fit a nonlinear trend

Tags: data-analysis

I'm trying to guess a function that would fit the non-oscillating part of the following curve:

[image]

I tried something in the form of $y = 1 - e^{-ax}$ and $tan^{-1}(ax)$, but it didn't work since the trend becomes horizontal for extremely low values of $y$.

Are there any better suggestions to try?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try a simple $y(x) = a\,x^{b}$ ? It seems that it might work with $0<b<1$.

Comment: What about $(1-e^{ax})b$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I tried $y = ax^b$ but. couldn't get a decent slope. I will try $b(1 - e^{ax})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

```
a = 0.05;
b = 1/2000;
r = 0.004;
y = a (1 - Exp[-b t]) + r Sin[10 2 Pi/2900 t]
Plot[y, {t, 0, 3000}, AspectRatio -> 0.8]
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Adding the sine helped me too!